# For-loops in R: "all arguments must have the same length"

Tags: r, for-loop

Im a beginner and Im sorry this question is very similar to one I have asked before, only this time I trying to use `for-loops`.

I want to do [this on my data](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/quantitative-data/frequency-distribution-quantitative-data)

In the ex. on this page, they only show how to do it for one column. I want to use `for-loops` to be able to do it for ALL columns. I have modified this, from the "Answer" section on the linked page:

```
for (i in x) {freq = table(cut,na.rm=TRUE)}
```

This returns the error `all arguments must have the same length`

Do anyone know what Im doing wrong? Columns in my vector are of different lengths, so all except one has a lot of `NA`.

Again, sorry for naive and very similar question...

Comment: If you please update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) it will be much easier to help you. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, but its all in the linked page, and I really dont get how to format (coding) the questions correctly..

Comment: Don't use a for-loop. Instead, use `lapply`, like `lapply(mydf, function(i) FUNCTION_I_WANT_TO_DO_TO_EACH_COLUMN)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from you using `na.rm = TRUE` as if it was a valid option to `table`. It is not, hence it is treated as one of the `...` arguments to `table` and since `length(TRUE)` is not equal to `length(cut)`, you get the error.

You probably meant to use `useNA = "no"` instead.

Comment: Good catch! That was it.

Comment: Thanks to Thomas and flodel, this fixed the problem: freq = lapply(x,function(i)table(cut,useNA="no"))

Comment: @flodel Kindly add a full code as I am facing the same issue and could not figure it out even after reading your reply.